# I am converting vb4 16 bit application to vb6 32 bit application. How to convert librarys

Tags: vb6

I have vb4 16bit app. I want to convert these two libraries...

```
Declare Function IsCharLower Lib "User" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function IsCharUpper Lib "User" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer
```

I want to convert to vb6 32 bit
How to do that

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For a small app, your comment could make sense. But it might be a big app. Migrating to a different technology could be a lot of work. Migrating to VB6 could be significantly less work - the VB6 IDE does a lot of it for you. And the VB6 runtime [is fully supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) - it's only the IDE that is unsupported - so that is a significant improvement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It would be short-sighted not to consider a rewrite. But it could be equally foolish not to consider a quick migration to VB6, in some circumstances. And, yes, you just use the IDE in an unsupported fashion. It's still an improvement over VB4. I used the VB6 IDE in an unsupported fashion today on some of our "legacy" big VB6 apps. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` in VB4 is `User32` in VB6 (and other Windows languages that refer to it).

```
Declare Function IsCharLower Lib "User32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function IsCharUpper Lib "User32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer
```

[`IsCharLower`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation

[`IsCharUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation

Comment: what is the difference between your code and this one : Declare Function IsCharLower Lib "Kernal32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer Declare Function IsCharUpper Lib "Kernal32" (ByVal cChar As Integer) As Integer

Comment: Other than the fact that yours uses `Kernel32` (which is not where the functions are located, and spells it wrong so it wouldn't work even if they were) and mine uses `User32`? Well, the biggest difference is that the Microsoft documentation says the functions are in `User32.DLL` and not `Kernel32`. I'll add the documentation link.